# Bash macOS terminal Ctrl+C to kill all processes

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, macos

I was trying to pipe the `rsync` output to a custom function, and use that to output custom information accordingly.

```
log_output() {
  while read -r dir; do
    last_slash_index=$(echo $dir | awk -F "/" '{print length($0)-length($NF)}')
    echo ${dir:(($last_slash_index))}
  done
}

rsync -avnh "/src/" "/dest" | log_output
```

In this particular instance, it outputs the last substring of the dir that doesn't contain any `/`. The problem is, when I use `ctrl+c` to attempt to terminate the process, the sub processes don't stop. Even though `rsync` has been stopped (as I could see that in the output), my own parsed results keeps being output into the terminal for some time. Is there anything that I can put in my code, so that when I press `ctrl+c`, everything terminates?

Comment: `ctrl+c` usually generates a SIGINT to the foreground process group, which should include both the rsync and anything else in the pipeline. how do you know your own function keeps going?

Comment: @thrig perhaps maybe my phrasing is incorrect. I meant that the function keeps outputting the parsed results generated by rsync in the terminal for some more time after pressing `ctrl+c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal from a <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> could take sometime between soon to never for all the processes in the foreground process group to respond to, especially if the system is very busy, or when a process is blocked on I/O. (This assumes that the terminal hasn't been configured to not generate a signal. See the `termios` manual concerning the `ISIG` flag for details. But I do not see indications of that in your question.) Timing might be better on a real-time operating system, though unix tends not be be that by default, and if a file is half-written when your "stop, now!!" happens, do you... stop and maybe corrupt the output? Wait a little bit longer in the hopes that the I/O flushes? How much longer?

Signal handlers (`trap` in shells, or whatever else might be built atop the `sigaction(2)` interface) will complicate matters, as will a complicated foreground process group (a shell pipeline). As a baseline you might see how this behaves with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>; `yes` and `cat` should not be doing anything complicated:

```
$ yes | cat
```

However, your terminal might be busy displaying all that output from `yes`, so could be slow to respond. That factor can be removed with:

```
$ yes | cat > /dev/null
```

or even

```
$ yes > /dev/null
```

If that is slow to respond to a <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then maybe your system is busy running something else?

Otherwise piping to a not very fast language like `bash` that forks out a new echo awk pipeline for each line of input plus some other code will be slower, especially if the system is not very good at forking lots of processes. It would be more efficient to pipe the output to an `awk` script (or some other programming language) that does all the calculations itself and more importantly replaces the [slow and problematic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445714/bash-remove-lines-from-text-file-starting-after-a-matched-row-applescript-ok/445716#445716) `while read` loop in `bash`. That way a <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> should be more quickly responded to, and less CPU will be used.

```
$ echo /etc/passwd | awk -F "/" '{print $0, length($0)-length($NF)}'
/etc/passwd 5
$ dir=/etc/passwd; echo ${dir:5}
passwd
$ echo /etc/passwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
passwd
```

So another thing to try with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> might be the somewhat simpler

```
rsync -avnh /src/ /dest | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

which appears to be similar to what all your shell function is doing, and it should be quite a bit more efficient with the CPU.